# How to put a loader in ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loader

One is a small code that allows me to view error messages when the form fields are empty or when everything is fine. What I would like to do is enter a loader or text to indicate that the submitted action is being processed. I really don't know where to start, can someone help me understand how to achieve this?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    
    $('.mts-edit-account').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

    //Ajax Handling Error
        var $form = $(this);
        jQuery.post(
      $form.attr('action'), 
      $form.serialize(), 
      function(data) {
        jQuery('.newdiv').html(data);
          }, 'json',
      
    );

    //Ajax function
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "post",
      data: jQuery(".mts-edit-account").serialize(),
    }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you mean show a loading notification?

Comment: Yes, i want to show a notification loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly put the loader in your HTML file where you want to display it. i.e: below the submit button

```
   <img 
        src="https://thumbs.gfycat.com/PessimisticGlamorousDunnart-size_restricted.gif" 
        class="loader" 
        alt="Loader"
        height=25 
        width=25 
    >
```

Then add CSS for this loader:

```
  .loader{
      display:none;
   }
```

Then put the below code in jQuery:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.mts-edit-account').on('submit', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "your_url",
            data: $(".mts-edit-account").serialize(),
            beforeSend: function() {
               $(".loader").show();
            },
            success: function(msg) {
              $(".loader").hide();
            }
          });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX requests using jQuery allows you to handle request completion, failure or success using the returned value from `ajax()` function. In your case you need to start by showing the loader before starting the request, then hide on completion. To do that, you can use `always()` function. That will make sure it's always called in case of success or failure.

```
// Show loader
jQuery.ajax({
    // ..
}).always(() => {
    // Hide loader
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I appreciate it very much. But I'm a newbie and don't know exactly how to use the code in your answer with mine. I'm sorry, but could you give some additional details? I would be grateful. Thanks again.

Comment: Just add the `always()` function after your `ajax()` call and use to hide loader